# Bulk insert into sql from an array in VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to build a button in excel that would upload the selected region into a table in the sql server. The first row would be automatically treated as the column headers.

How to go on about this? What I want is simplicity & super-fast uploading.

This is my idea ---

I would take the selected region and then save it as a .txt file and then run a bulk insert statement on it. Is there a method to directly bulk insert the selected region (maybe take it in a variant array first), without first saving it as a .txt file?

Also, if there is a more efficient method, then do propose.

Comment: `sql server` mentioned in the question but tagged `mysql` ?

Comment: how big is the table likely to be?

Comment: @whytheq no general limit per se. From 10-10^7 rows.

Comment: 10^7 ....from Excel - how? (1 mill rows are available in an Excel worksheet)

Answer (score 4):

I would start with a simple ADO connection to the server and execute a bunch of INSERT INTO statements and see how it is performance-wise. If that doesn't work, then you can look at creating a text file with the same INSERT INTO statements. That may be faster, I really don't know.  Here's some code to convert a range into the SQL statements you need

```
Function RangeToInsert(rRng As Range) As String

    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim aReturn() As String
    Dim aCols() As String
    Dim aVals() As Variant

    Const sINSERT As String = "INSERT INTO MyTable "
    Const sVAL As String = " VALUES "

    'Read in data
    vaData = rRng.Value

    'Create arrays
    ReDim aReturn(1 To UBound(vaData))
    ReDim aCols(1 To UBound(vaData, 2))
    ReDim aVals(1 To UBound(vaData, 2))

    'Fill column name array from first row
    For j = LBound(vaData, 2) To UBound(vaData, 2)
        aCols(j) = vaData(1, j)
    Next j

    'Go through the rest of the rows
    For i = LBound(vaData, 1) + 1 To UBound(vaData, 1)

        'Fill a temporary array
        For j = LBound(vaData, 2) To UBound(vaData, 2)
            aVals(j) = vaData(i, j)
        Next j

        'Build the string into the main array
        aReturn(i) = sINSERT & "(" & Join(aCols, ",") & ")" & sVAL & "(" & Join(aVals, ",") & ");"
    Next i

    RangeToInsert = Join(aReturn, vbNewLine)

End Function
```

Here's what the output would look like with some fake data I threw together:

```
?rangetoinsert(selection)

INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (97,100,53,27,14,53,94,43);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (21,96,69,60,70,8,35,54);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (8,12,78,38,82,67,41,53);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (15,32,89,100,61,78,16,37);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (46,37,75,66,66,93,19,45);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (82,30,56,10,99,2,1,29);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (98,39,98,96,95,60,16,73);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (65,79,69,70,74,86,15,59);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (30,37,12,57,86,94,6,53);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (1,20,91,65,20,26,96,57);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (81,7,68,65,56,27,81,80);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (94,42,43,33,46,82,44,24);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (88,48,34,83,58,64,36,90);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (51,28,43,70,12,29,96,27);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (62,54,76,86,92,41,40,84);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (11,21,32,30,65,6,22,75);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (44,72,38,73,44,93,4,16);
INSERT INTO MyTable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8) VALUES (39,90,96,16,9,6,17,50);
```

You could put this into an Execute call on your ADO connection or write it out to a text file. I can't imagine that anything else would be faster than using SQL statements. For instance, you could update the .Fields.Value properties as you loop through an updatable recordset, but there's no way that's going to be faster than this.

If you're doing a million rows, nothing in VBA will be fast, though. So keep that in mind.

Comment: "*If you're doing a million rows, nothing in VBA will be fast*"  While that's *generally* true (I've said it myself), there is one way around this: dump the data to a delimited text file and then import it with the SQL Server BCP utility.  Kludgy, but it's the only truly fast way to load 1 million rows from VBA.

Comment: FYI: the text file with INSERT statements approach isn't likely to be any faster that straight-VBA though.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The bulk insert statement is indeed the fastest. I have no doubts about it. The problem lies in converting the excel sheet into a pipe delimited text file. I dont know how fast that will be, as I will have to append a pipe after every cell and then print it in a txt file. So that means a brute force double loop of the order (no. of rows)*(no. of columns). Thats why I'm looking for a method to Bulk Insert from an array and not a txt file.

Comment: I was thinking that the text file might be able to be asynchronous, which could be the same as being faster depending on the situation. It's good to know they're the same though. Can you automate the upload of a pipe delimited file from VBA or do you have to do that through SQLServer

Comment: @DickKusleika how would you deal with text values in this case, where the values need to be surrounded by quotation marks?

Comment: @Rym you just have to put the single quotes in there manually. If your first and third columns are strings, it might look like `For j = LBound(vaData, 2) To UBound(vaData, 2): If j = 1 Or j = 3 Then : aVals(j) = "'" & vaData(i,j) & "'": Else:  aVals(j) = vaData(i, j): End If: Next j`

Comment: @DickKusleika Check, figured as much but I was hoping there would be a more elegant way of doing this :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write a function (mine is called insert form).

```
Function insertForm(givenRange As Range) As String
--Convert each row to a string format of values
--Each value needs to have all instances of ' replaced with ''
--Each value needs to be wrapped in '
--Use Join with comma(,) to join all the values and put brackets around the whole thing
--This is the insert form for one row.
--You can get the other rows by writing the result of the function recursively
--If givenRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    --insertForm = insertForm & ", " & insertForm(givenRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(givenRange.Rows.Count - 1, givenRange.Columns.Count))
--End If
End Function
```

So if I select 4 columns with 2 rows that contain

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

This function creates ('1','2','3','4'),('5','6','7','8')
I can then use this in the INSERT SQL statement as follows:

INSERT INTO TableName VALUES InsertForm(Range)