# Any way to improve the speed of this VBA loop to insert data into SQL?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a VBA loop that inserts around 120,000 rows into a SQL table.

I have read that using a loop for large datasets is quite time consuming (which I've found, this takes over 10 minutes to complete)

If someone could suggest something to me to maybe bulk insert this data as a range or something?

Thanks guys!

```
Sub export_to_sql()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim C1, C2, C3, C4 As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim strFile As Variant
Dim shtname As String
ChDir "xxx"
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
If strFile = False Then
Exit Sub
Else: End If



    ' *** Open workbook first ***
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
    shtname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
    lastrow = wbk.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Sheets(shtname)

    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SERVER\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xx; Password=xxxxxxxx; "

    ' Delete table data
    conn.Execute "DELETE FROM EcommerceTablename"

    'Skip the header row
    RowNo = 2

    'Loop until empty cell in Col 1
    Do Until .Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""
        C1 = .Cells(RowNo, 1)
        C2 = .Cells(RowNo, 2)
        C3 = .Cells(RowNo, 3)
        C4 = .Cells(RowNo, 4)

        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table

        conn.Execute "insert into EcommerceTablename ([Col_1_C], [Col_2_C], [Col_3_C], [Col_4_C]) values ('" & C1 & "', '" & C2 & "', '" & C3 & "', '" & C4 & "')"

        RowNo = RowNo + 1
    Loop


    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `bulk insert` rather than inserting row by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost part is the roundtrip on the connection, so try to send multiple insert on each `execute`

create a counter variable `i` so you insert 10 row each time

```
 Do Until .Cells(RowNo, 1) = "" 
     i = i+1;
```

save the command in a string, separate each instruction with semicolon `;`

```
strSQL = strSQL + "insert into EcommerceTablename ([Col_1_C], [Col_2_C], [Col_3_C], [Col_4_C]) values ('" & C1 & "', '" & C2 & "', '" & C3 & "', '" & C4 & "');"
```

execute 10 insert each time.

```
if i mod 10 = 0 then
   conn.Execute strSQL
```

after loop end insert the remaining rows.

```
loop
conn.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: Thanks Juan.... tried this but it takes a few minutes still. Any ideas how to do a bulk insert as suggested by @Gordon Linoff  ?

Comment: check this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837554/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-an-array-in-vba

Answer (score 2):

If you really want speed, you should consider using the bulk copy utility, `bcp`.  Have your VBA generate output to a file and then have `bcp` slurp the file into the database.

My syntax might be a bit off on the BCP, but I think with a little tweaking you can get it exactly the way you want:

```
  Dim outputArray(4) As String
  Dim col As Integer

  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFile)

  Open "c:\Temp\UploadData.dat" For Output As #1

  With wbk.Sheets(1)
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    RowNo = 2

    Do Until .Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""
      For col = 1 To 4
        outputArray(col) = .Cells(RowNo, col)
      Next col

      Print #1, Join(outputArray, "|")

      RowNo = RowNo + 1
    Loop

    conn.Open "<your connection string>"
    conn.Execute "DELETE FROM EcommerceTablename"
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

  End With

  Close #1

  System ("bcp EcommerceTablename in c:\Temp\UploadData.dat -S SERVER\SQL2008R2 " & _
      "-c -t""|"" -U xx -P xxxxxxxxxx")
```

Again, you may want to look these up to verify, but the basic syntax is:

```
bcp <table> <in/out (upload/download> <file> <options>
```

The options I listed, to the best of my knowledge are:

- -S server
- -U Userid
- -P Password
- -c character input (-n[ative] is useful for making backups)
- -t delimiter

Also, provided you have permissions on the table to do so, `truncate` is significantly faster than `delete from` if all you really want to do is wipe and reload the table.  If you don't have permissions, see if your DBA will give you access to a stored procedure that will do the truncate.

As a final alternative, I'd recommend the use of a transaction and bind variables.  Both of these will enable you to significantly improve the speed of your inserts through normal ADO commands (without bcp).  I think if you test bcp, you probably won't want to do anything else.

Comment: Here is an example of bind variables for SQL Server/VBA.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34273330/1278553 -- when at all possible you really should use bind variables (parameters) instead of literals.  As far as a transaction, you would create a transaction first and then commit the transaction at the end.  If you don't do this, then every single insert has its own commit, which takes more time and is considerably harder on the database.  Let me know if any of that is not clear.  The transaction is instantiated off of the connection object.

Comment: please see this article here, I'm having a few issues with that code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498637/adodb-connection-to-upload-data-to-sql-using-bind-variables

Answer (score -1):

```
Range("A1").Select

 Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim sFirstName, sLastName As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SWD-03\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PDS_Testing;User ID=Sa;password=pass.123;"

        'Skip the header row
        iRowNo = 2

        'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 4) = ""
        sPartno = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
        sBatchID = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
        sDimension = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)

            'Generate and execute sql statement
            ' to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
   conn.Execute "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Project1 WHERE ID = '" & sID & "' ) " & _
         "INSERT INTO dbo.Project1 (Partno  ,BatchID ,Dimension) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & sPartno & "', '" & sBatchID & "','" & sDimension & "' )"

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Loop
        MsgBox "Saved Sucessfully."
        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
    End With
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Button14_Click()
Range("A1").Select

 Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim sFirstName, sLastName As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SWD-03\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PDS_Testing;User ID=Sa;password=pass.123;"

        'Skip the header row
        iRowNo = 2

        'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 4) = ""
        sPartno = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
        sBatchID = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
        sDimension = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)

            'Generate and execute sql statement
            ' to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
   conn.Execute "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Project1 WHERE ID = '" & sID & "' ) " & _
         "INSERT INTO dbo.Project1 (Partno  ,BatchID ,Dimension) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & sPartno & "', '" & sBatchID & "','" & sDimension & "' )"

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Loop
        MsgBox "Saved Sucessfully."
        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
    End With


End Sub
```